# Force my page to be http and not https?

Tags: jquery, security, http, https, server

I received a folder with ftp access on a university (faculty) server, and cannot upload html pages that will be served as http. All are served as https. What to do? 
I have no control over the server, just a directory and location to put my files under public_html.

When served as https I get the warning "shield" in chrome that there is unsecure code.

Is this because of something in the script? 
I'm using jquery from the 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
and listening for an 'ended' event of an audio control so I can enable the submit button. That's all. 
The code works if I accept it, but I don't want the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google also serves up these js files over https, so you can use that:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

which should solve the problem, unless you have other css/js/image references which are http://

An alternative:
try:

```js
 <script>
    if (document.location.protocol == "https:")
        document.location='http://yourwebsite..'; 
    </script>
```

Comment: that simple?!  OK. Still what can I do so that the page I put on the website is served as simple http? Or is that impossible?  (I read that a server serving secure content should not server regular http because that could enable a security breach).

The truth is that I don't really understand how the server "knows" what to serve as http or https. Is it per directory or per a list of files? And is there anything I can do as the uploader of content to determine how my page will be served?

Comment: The server serves what's been requested, unless it does its own redirect at the web server level.  I've edited my post to provide an alternative which you may be able to use depending on your server setup.

Comment: Its obviously doing an automatic redirect, and Not serving the original http call. Then it throws a warning that the script is calling non secure code. Changing all my code to https did the trick, but I was wondering if I could overcome the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Change `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`

to
`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`

Any and all externally loaded resources should be via https otherwise it'll throw that warning.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to just refer to the assets without the scheme:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
```

It will automatically load the resource under the same protocol used to load the page (eg: `http` for `http` requests, `https` for secure ones). It's transparent.

Additionally, I would suggest *always* supporting `https`, even if there is insecure content on the page. Insecure content does affect security, but the more you load over `http`, the bigger the attack surface is. Allowing users to use `https` will be better in the long run.